# Backbone listenTo not working

Tags: events, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have the following working code, and I was planning to replace object.on calls with object.listenTo calls:

```
setField: function(field) {
  if (this.field) this.field.off(null, null, this);

  if (field) {
    this.field = field;
    this.field.on('validate', this.renderErrors, this);
  }
  return this;
},
```

and this is the new version

```
setField: function(field) {
  if (this.field) this.stopListening(this.field);

  if (field) {
    this.field = field;
    this.listenTo(this.field, 'validate', this.renderErrors);
  }
  return this;
},
```

but some how it's not working. The method this.renderErrors is no being called with the second version.

The strange thing is I updated al the rest of my app accordingly without any trouble.

I'm sure there must be something pretty silly I'm missing.

BTW, this is the code used by the field to raise the event

```
[...]
  this.trigger('validate', this.errors);

  this.error = !this.isValid();
  return this.errors;
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the cause of the problem

I was destroying the view with the setField method (which released all the events attached to it when using listenTo instead of just object.on).

It was a bug on my own code, so listenTo works ok

Leaving this question open in case someone wants to find an example of how to migrate from observee.on to observer.listenTo

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used the new listenTo and stopListening yet, but I can see that in your new version, you're calling stopListening against the **parameter** `field`, meaning your view is still listening to the previously-visible `this.field`

```
setField: function(field) {
    if (this.field) this.stopListening(field);
```

Your existing version calls `off` on `this.field`.

Try using:

`if (this.field) this.stopListening(this.field);`

Comment: I solved the bug you pointed (also updated the question), but the problem is still there... any other idea???

Comment: are you seeing an event being fired at all? Like if you were to manually add a listener via browser console?